# converting nested loop to a better format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I wrote the following code that goes over a csv file and checks if a user did two actions in less than 10 seconds:

```
import csv
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import sys

csvFileName = 'edited.csv'




with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)

        for index, row in enumerate(csvReader):
            userIdentity = row['useridentity']
            eventTime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['eventtime'])
            for subIndex, subRow in enumerate(csvReader):
                subUserIdentity = subRow['useridentity']
                subEventTime = dateutil.parser.parse(subRow['eventtime'])
                if subIndex - index == 1  and userIdentity == subUserIdentity:
                    if subEventTime - eventTime < datetime.timedelta(seconds=10):
                        print('heads up!')
                        print(eventTime)
                        print(subEventTime)
```

'eventtime' contains a time in an iso 8601 format which is converted to a datetime object
There are 2 problem:

1. Nesting means it runs over the file ^2 times
2. On this format if I want to change it to compare to 3 actions instead of 2 it will need another nested for loop

I would to understand what is the better and correct way to write something like this.

Update this is my updated attempt but it is duplicating results:

```
import csv
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import sys

csvFileName = 'edited.csv'

def seqCounter(index, currentTime):
    tmpIndex = 0
    with open(csvFileName, 'r') as tmpFile:
        tmpReader = csv.DictReader(tmpFile)
        for row in tmpReader:
            if tmpIndex <= index:
                tmpIndex += 1
                continue
            eventTime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['eventtime'])
            if eventTime - currentTime < datetime.timedelta(seconds=2) and eventTime - currentTime > datetime.timedelta(seconds=0):
                print('heads up')
                print(row['useridentity'])
                print(eventTime)
                print(currentTime)



with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)

        for index, row in enumerate(csvReader):
            currentTime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['eventtime'])
            seqCounter(index, currentTime)
```

Comment: What is your nested loop doing? Can you explain with some data?

Comment: "Nesting means it runs over the file ^2 times" -- not in this case since you're iterating over the same iterable, i.e., when you're done with the inner loop, you're outer loop exits since you've already used up your iterable.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect from the whole function? I guess you want to find occurrence of event by a user in a row in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: Seyed guessed correctly, justin you're right, my code doesn't work, it stopped as you said.

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you are only checking the previous event by the same user. Instead of looping through the whole file again for every entry, this will store the last event by the same user in a `dict`. This lets you loop through the whole file exactly once.

```py
with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
        user_events = dict()
        for index, row in enumerate(csvReader):
            userIdentity = row['useridentity']
            eventTime = dateutil.parser.parse(row['eventtime'])

            # Get the last event for this user 
            lastEventTime = user_events.get(userIdentity)
            if lastEventTime:
                if lastEventTime - eventTime < datetime.timedelta(seconds=10):
                    print('heads up!')
                    print(eventTime)
                    print(lastEventTime)

            # Set the one we just looked at as the last event
            user_events[userIdentity] = eventTime
```